# Do footnotes help or hinder readability?

Tags: footnotes

When I read a text the first time, I usually also read all the footnotes, since they may be important to understanding. This interrupts my reading flow, and I think simple parentheses would have been easier.

With footnotes, you can simply ignore them if you already know them very easily, but I am not really sure if ignoring parentheses is that hard either.

What is a general rule for parentheses and footnotes?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see this being on-topic: there is nothing about TeX here.

Comment: True, but which site would be the right one?

Comment: A major advantage of footnotes over parentheses or parenthetical commas is that a footnote can be one ore more full sentences.  They can therefore be used (sparingly) for a more in-depth explanation than an inline construction.  If you find yourself using too many footnotes, you probably need to avoid so many tangents in your writing!

Comment: although off-topic, it might be worth considering endnotes if the desire is to *really* move the extra material out of the way.

Comment: Personally, i find footnotes very distracting, in that it is hard to go back after reading a note. Even worse, sometimes when browsing you see a note that mentions something relevant, and you get to chase the place where it it called

Comment: @vonbrand That is exactly what I find annoying as well.

Comment: @barbarabeeton In that case, I think I would create an appendix and reference that inline.

Answer (score 2):

Footnotes are designed to move bracketted text out of the way.

The idea here is that one can expand on secondary matter, while giving the reader the chance to skip this material at a glance.  In part, the idea is largely spoilt by mixing bibliographic and bracketted text into the same list, because then many footnotes simply refer to (opcit, p18), instead of giving a lengthy discussion on the side.

In `\LaTeX` for example, one gets the idea of what bracketed text does by reading the source, because the `\footnote{text}` appears directly where the rune might appear.  So eg

The measure of 24 carat\footnote{some very long text goes here} makes a solidus\footnote{some commnents on the Moorish metcal goes here.}. disolves neatly to "The measure of 24 carats² make a solidus³."  with attached footnotes, which may or may not be read.